# Should 3 Unsalvageable be disputed by one OK?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I think if out of 4, 3 users say a question is unsalvageable and even has negative votes it should be useful and not disputed.

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8596993) the 4th user pressed "Looks Ok" by mistake or something of the sort.
At least maybe get a 5th reviewer to weigh in, instead of disputing all 3 flags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Three Unsalvageable reviews completes the task - your example [is now in the close queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8597092).

The single "OK" review was ignored.

Comment: Oh wow, yesterday when I posted the question my flag appeared as disputed, now it is helpful. Is this possible? Or I just was completely blind and saw the wrong thing? I checked several times.

Comment: Was probably marked "active".